# Replicate texture effect from 2d to 3d OpenGL

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, 3d, texture-mapping

I have a 2D OpenGL project for android of a .png as a texture on a Square.  I would like to replicate the effect on all 6 sides of a 3D cube. I tried matching the format as closely as possible, but ran into a unexpected stopping issue.

My first code block:

```
package book.BouncySquare;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.*;
import android.opengl.*;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import java.nio.IntBuffer;

import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL11;
/**
 * A vertex shaded square.
 */
class Square
{
public Square()
{
    float vertices[] = 
        {
            -1.0f, -1.0f,
            1.0f, -1.0f,
            -1.0f,  1.0f,
            1.0f,  1.0f
        }; 

    byte maxColor=(byte)255;

    byte colors[] = 
        {
            maxColor,maxColor,       0,maxColor,
            0,       maxColor,maxColor,maxColor,
            0,              0,       0,maxColor,
            maxColor,       0,maxColor,maxColor
        }; 

    byte indices[] = 
        {
            0, 3, 1,
            0, 2, 3
        };


    float[] textureCoords =     
        {                       
            0.0f, 0.0f,
            1.0f, 0.0f,
            0.0f, 1.0f,
            1.0f, 1.0f      
        };

    ByteBuffer vbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4);
    vbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    mFVertexBuffer = vbb.asFloatBuffer();
    mFVertexBuffer.put(vertices);
    mFVertexBuffer.position(0);

    mColorBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(colors.length);
    mColorBuffer.put(colors);
    mColorBuffer.position(0);

    mIndexBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(indices.length);
    mIndexBuffer.put(indices);
    mIndexBuffer.position(0);

    ByteBuffer tbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(textureCoords.length * 4);
    tbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    mTextureBuffer = tbb.asFloatBuffer();
    mTextureBuffer.put(textureCoords);
    mTextureBuffer.position(0); 
}

public void draw(GL10 gl)
{ 
    gl.glVertexPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, mFVertexBuffer);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glColorPointer(4, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0, mColorBuffer);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);                //1
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_BLEND);                 //2 

    gl.glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_ONE, GL10.GL_SRC_COLOR);         //3
    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);      //4 

    gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT,0, mTextureBuffer);   //5
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);        //6 

    gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);          //7

    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);       //8
}

private int[] textures = new int[1];

public int createTexture(GL10 gl, Context contextRegf, int resource) 
{
    Bitmap tempImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(contextRegf.getResources(), resource); // 1

    gl.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0); // 2
    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]); // 3

    GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, tempImage, 0); // 4

    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR); // 5a
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR); // 5b   

    tempImage.recycle();//6

    return resource;
}

private Float mTransY;
public FloatBuffer  mTextureBuffer;
private FloatBuffer mFVertexBuffer;
private ByteBuffer  mColorBuffer;
private ByteBuffer  mIndexBuffer;
```

}

My second code block:

```
package book.BouncyCube1;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import java.nio.IntBuffer;

import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL11;

import android.view.MotionEvent;

/**
 * A vertex shaded cube.
 */
class Cube
{

    float[] mVertices = 
    {
            -1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
             1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
             1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,
            -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,

            -1.0f,  1.0f,-1.0f,
             1.0f,  1.0f,-1.0f,
             1.0f, -1.0f,-1.0f,
            -1.0f, -1.0f,-1.0f
    }; 

    float maxColor=1.0f;

    float[] mColors = 
    {
            maxColor,   maxColor,      0.0f,maxColor,
            0.0f,       maxColor,  maxColor,maxColor,
            0.0f,           0.0f,      0.0f,maxColor,
            maxColor,       0.0f,  maxColor,maxColor,

            maxColor,       0.0f,      0.0f,maxColor,
            0.0f,       maxColor,      0.0f,maxColor,
            0.0f,           0.0f,  maxColor,maxColor,
            0.0f,           0.0f,      0.0f,maxColor
    }; 

    float[] mNormals = 
    {
        0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
        0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,

        1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,


        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,

        0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f,
        0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f,  

        0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,

        -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,

    };

    byte[] tfan1 =                  
    {
            1,0,3,
            1,3,2,
            1,2,6,
            1,6,5,
            1,5,4,
            1,4,0               
    };

    byte[] tfan2 =                  
    {
            7,4,5,
            7,5,6,
            7,6,2,
            7,2,3,
            7,3,0,
            7,0,4
    };

    public Cube()
    {      
        mTfan1 = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(tfan1.length);
        mTfan1.put(tfan1);
        mTfan1.position(0);

        mTfan2 = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(tfan2.length);
        mTfan2.put(tfan2);
        mTfan2.position(0);
    }

    public void draw(GL10 gl)
    {
        gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL11.GL_FLOAT, 0,makeFloatBuffer(mVertices));
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

        gl.glColorPointer(4, GL11.GL_FLOAT, 0,makeFloatBuffer(mColors));
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

        gl.glNormalPointer(GL11.GL_FLOAT, 0,makeFloatBuffer(mNormals));
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);

        gl.glDrawElements( gl.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 6 * 3, gl.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, mTfan1);
        gl.glDrawElements( gl.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 6 * 3, gl.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, mTfan2);
    }

     protected static FloatBuffer makeFloatBuffer(float[] arr) 
     {
          ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(arr.length*4);
          bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
          FloatBuffer fb = bb.asFloatBuffer();
          fb.put(arr);
          fb.position(0);
          return fb;
     }


    private FloatBuffer mFVertexBuffer;
    private FloatBuffer mNormalBuffer;
    private ByteBuffer  mColorBuffer;
    private ByteBuffer  mIndexBuffer;
    private ByteBuffer  mTfan1;
    private ByteBuffer  mTfan2;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL only supports one set of indices for a draw call, and these indices are used to address all vertex attributes (positions, colors, normals). Looking at your second version, you have 8 positions, 8 colors, and 12 normals. One way to notice that this can't work is that the range of your indices is 0..7, so not all of your 12 normals are used.

What you need to do is create a OpenGL vertex for every unique combination of position, color and normal. For a cube, you will end up with 24 vertices. While the cube has only 8 corners, there are 3 different normals at each corner, and 8 * 3 = 24. While the cube has only 6 different normals, each normal is used for 4 corners, and 6 * 4 = 24.

So define an array with 24 positions, an array with 24 colors, and an array with 24 normals, matched up to define all 24 vertices. Or one array with all of these 3 attributes interleaved. Then define your index array to connect the 24 vertices with the correct triangles, and draw.